# Macro not working as expected in excel 2010

Tags: vba, excel-2010

I have taken over an excel doc with several macros. I am not well versed in how this works but have been able to update and fix it until now. The following script is to do a file SaveAs using text in the excel document as the file name. When I run the macro, I get Run-time error '1004': The item with the specified name wasn't found. I'm stuck on what it is looking for and not finding. Any feedback is appreciated.

```
Sub save_file()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("QUOTE").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Option Button 1").Select
    Selection.Delete
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Option Button 6").Select
    Selection.Delete
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 3")).Select
    Selection.Delete
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Rows("8:11").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, 
Transpose:=False
    Range("D13").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, 
Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("E3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, 
Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheets(Array("Main", "S", "H", "AP", "SE", "DC", "UI", "LX", "TS", "SS", "ALL NOTES", 
"Customer List", "SHIPPING", "SING", "COSTS", "BOM's")).Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
If Range("c17").Characters.Count < 25 Then
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Application.GetSaveAsFilename(Range("E3") & " (" & Range("C17") & ")", 
"Excel files (*.xlsm), *.xlsm"), Password:=""
Else
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Application.GetSaveAsFilename(Range("E3"), "Excel files (*.xlsm), 
*.xlsm"), Password:=""
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: First thing I wonder is, are you sure all of those sheets actually exist in the workbook where this is running?

Comment: Upon which line is the error being thrown?

Comment: Verify that all objects in your workbook (sheets, shapes, etc) are present and have the same names specified there in the code. Also, yes...what JNevill said...need to know the line that threw the error.

Comment: One or more of those shapes does not exist (at least with the expected name).